# Apache2.4.54 - Rewrite does not work in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this .htaccess file in `/path/to/project/`

```xml
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !system

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/some/folders/$2.php [PT]
</IfModule>
```

and, as you can see, I want to redirect `https://example.com/path/to/project/folder` to `https://example.com/path/to/project/some/folders/folder`.

I know that this was answered like 1M times, but even a `RewriteRule ^ /` with no conditions doesn't work.

I have enabled mod_rewrite and checked that it was enabled, by including a `Header set` in the `<IfModule>` and it worked.

I have checked that `AllowOverride All` is in the `/path/to/project/` directory, like so:

```xml
<Directory ${APACHE_ROOT_DIR}/path/to/project>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I have no ideas anymore. I hope someone can help me.

UPDATE:

I tested the rewrite on another server and there the rewrite works. I copied the exact rewrite and it doesn't work. I even recreated the filestructure. Now only the `mod_rewrite` itself has a problem or the server `VirtualHost` or simular has a problem.

UPDATE 2:

I got it working in the `sites-available/default-ssl.conf` but not in the `.htaccess`. So the problem is in `.htaccess` and with `mod_rewrite` in combination. Because `.htaccess` works with `Header set test test` and `mod_rewrite` works in the `default-ssl.conf`.

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ some/folders/$1 [L]`

Comment: @anubhava that doesn't work either.

Comment: I did this too & I said already that .htaccess kinda works, because you could set headers.

Comment: Why do you have `$2.php` in your rule? That doesn't seem to be part of your requirements.

Comment: The `$2` matches with `([^/]+)` as the end of the URL. See the 2. section with the example.

Comment: I know that I can't write `<Directory ...>` in my `.htaccess` and I don't use it here anyways.

Comment: Inside `path/to/project/.htaccess`, just keep only one line  `RewriteRule foo /bar [L,R]` and visit `https://example.com/path/to/project/`

Comment: With the `RewriteEngine on`, right?

Comment: I tried with and without `RewriteEngine on`. Both do nothing.

Comment: Have a suspicion that .htaccess is not in use

Comment: But if I put `Header set test test` for example, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should track down the possible problems step by step.
*Please do **not** join some of the tests, as each test requires its own prove!*

While doing this, please stay at your required `virtualhost.conf`. Jumping between `default-ssl.conf` and your `virtualhost.conf` might give some hints, but is not helpful, when trying to track down a problem systematically in a row of tests.

#### 1. Access rights

Please verify that the visitors are allowed to access the directory. So add `Require all granted`, if not yet present:

File:  `httpd.conf` or included `*.conf`

```php
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/myhost/htdoc/PATH/TO/PROJECT">
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

After this reconfiguration a restart of the Apache daemon required:

At the web server issue the command:

```bash
apachectl -k graceful
```

Open your project URL `http://example.com/PATH/TO/PROJECT/`:
You should *not* see an `403 Access denied`
=> Else this problem has to be solved first. (index file0 present? / Apache restarted properly? / Any rewrite rules?)

***STATUS-Update:*** *Functionality OK*

#### 2. Check the usage of the `.htaccess` file

By the `AllowOverride All` the usage of the `.htaccess` file should work. Please test it, as typos etc. can render invalid any assumption:

Add a line of nonsense in the `.htaccess` of your project folder:

File: `/var/www/vhosts/myhost/htdoc/PATH/TO/PROJECT/.htaccess`

```bash
asflksdflkj
```

Calling the page `http://example.com/PATH/TO/PROJECT/` should produce a

```
500  Server Error
```

Remove the line of nonsense in the `.htaccess` and call the page again:
=> The `500` error should disappear.

*The `.htaccess` is evaluated by Apache, if the behavior is as described.*

***STATUS-Update:*** *Functionality OK*

#### 3. Check the presence of the ReWrite Engine

To be sure, the rewrite engine is present AND the `.htaccess` file is accessed:
Delete or set as comment the module check for `mod_rewrite.c`, but leave the active the `RewriteEngine On`:

```bash
# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
# </IfModule>
```

Calling the page `http://example.com/PATH/TO/PROJECT/` should ***not*** produce a

```
500  Server Error
```

=> If this `500` happens, the module `mod_rewrite` is not loaded.

When tested positive, you can re-enable the module check.
*For my projects, I think twice about this step as it might be better to clearly see the server problem than to get obscure side effects by not evaluated rewrite rules.*

***STATUS-Update:*** *Functionality OK*

#### 4. Check for concurrent ReWrite rules

Rewrite rules get evaluated dir by dir:

```
1.  /.htaccess
2.  /PATH/.htaccess
3.  /PATH/TO/.htaccess
4.  /PATH/TO/PROJECT/.htaccess
```

So any rules in parent directories might manipulate the REQUEST_URI in an way that the project's directory will not be reached and no rule in there will be triggered.

=> If there are rules in the parent directories, disable them while testing.
=> Do not forget to check the apache CONF files for concurrent ReWrite rules.

To see ReWrite at work, enable the DEBUG feature. Extend your `LogLevel` for your VirtualHost definition:

```bash
LogLevel  notice rewrite:trace5
```

Now (after `apachectl -k graceful`) the error_log should be filled excessively.

For all rewrite rules in the parent dirs there should be the set of lines:

```bash
... applying pattern ...
... pass through ....

# or
... applying pattern ...
... RewriteCond: ....  => not-matched, ...
... pass through ....
```

For the lines of your project there should be the set of lines (and more) like:

```bash
... applying pattern ...
... RewriteCond: ....  => matched
... rewrite ....
```

How are the tests?
*=> might be useful to provide a logfile*

***STATUS-Update:***

1. *There are Rewrite rules executed before*
2. *None of the ReWrite rules exits evaluation by `[L]`eave.

   (`[L]` would not not be a problem, as after a `RewriteRule ... [L]` ReWrite will restart evaluation at the beginning)*
3. *At least one of the earlier evaluated ReWrite rules changes the URI of the project (added the DocumentRoot to the URI) in an unintended manner, triggering the problem.*
   ***=> Change of the rule in question solved the problem.***

#### 5. Define the proper `RewriteBase`

File:  `/var/www/vhosts/myhost/htdoc/PATH/TO/PROJECT/.htaccess`

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !system

RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/some/folders/$2.php [PT]
```

Depending on details and further context, another RewriteBase might be better. *(provide feedback? logfile?)*

---

For each step provide a short result, please.

Comment: First, thank you for the long and detailed tests

Comment: 1. I Have tested if I can access the `/path/to/project/` folder and it works. i have an index.php in there and it loads with no problems

Comment: 2. I have added `abcd` and nothing else in my `.htaccess` and i get a 500.

Comment: 3. I only wrote `RewriteEngine On` and it does **not** produce a 500.

Comment: 4.  I hav e in total 3 rewrite rules: 1. All http requests are rewritten to https 2. All PDFs are rewriten to a PDF viewer 3. All https requests from my internal network are rewritten to some .local domain. - All Rewrites dont have the [L] flag and allow further rewrites. The path is not altered, only for files with `.pdf` as extension it is changed to the viewer path

Comment: Thanks, i have found the problem. It was the Rewrite to my internal network. it made something with the URI and killed the other Rewrites. I have no idea why, but now it works.

Comment: Fine, so Check #4 gave the kick. — But with rewrite rules one should be careful and understand why they are doing something. So I wouldn't be calm until all rules and their possible side effects are understood and under control.

Comment: I have checked the other Rewrites as well and figured out that `^$` makes the problem in RewriteRule. I changed all to `.*`.

Comment: I wished there were better and easier tools to check and make RewriteRules. I had found [htaccess.madewithlove.com](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/) but it doesnt include the path or other server specific things to generate results. Or better debugging in another log file, like in Apache 2.2.

Comment: As you can define a separate `error_log` in each of your `VirtualHost` definitions by `ErrorLog /var/log/apache/mydom_error.log`, the log for debugging ReWrite ruels is quite exclusive. Note, there is no need to rise the log level for the other Apache error-log events:  `LogLevel  notice rewrite:trace5` — So the personal verification of the ReWrite rules works quite well for me. — It's quite usefull to start with `tail -fn0 error.log` and open only one URL to trigger ReWrite to see what happens within this single request.

Comment: Unfortunatelly these RegEx-testers like that you've linked only evaluate one rule or rule-set. They have no idea about other dependencies like those that might appear in parent folders. I prefer to test the rules locally in a virtual machine running apache and my sites and a test site as local editions. — Using `RewriteBase /PATH/TO/PROJECT/` with a fitted rule-set might be tougher in the first steps, but helps a lot (1) in limiting the rules' influence (2) reusing rules unchanged in other dirs (3) keeping the regex simpler (4) when shifting rules between `virtualhost.conf` and `.htaccess`.

Comment: Your right i can change the errorlog per virtual host but i cant seperate the rewrite from other errors without using the terminal. And yeah those tools are not the best for a specific need. But it is not allways possible to make a vm to test the rewrite and i will try to use RewriteBase more often to keep the reach in a certain directory.